# get description with snmp4j API

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I know that i can get IOD description from my local MIB.

Is there a way, using the SNMP4J to get that description from a remote device? how?

can some one point me in the right direction
thanks

Comment: http://www.snmp4j.org/ Please check out the stack diagram and find what you need.

Comment: Is it really a duplicate?  OP seems to want to get the description from the *remote* device, not from the MIB.  If that's what's wanted, then the answer would have to be "only if the the device provides its MIB or an equivalent mapping somehow".

Comment: Yes, I want from the remote device MIB. It's optional but it can be done.. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/configuration/guide/ffun_c/fcf014.html